# Passing a Rails controller defined local variable into a Turbo Frame Tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-7, hotwire-rails

I am a super newbie to rails but I am defining a local variable (a css class) and passing it to this partial

`render(partial: 'calendar_inventory', locals:{klass: params[:select]})`

Inside my partial I have a pagination occurring:

```
  <div class="grid-container" data-calendar-target="grid" data-action= "scroll->calendar#populateHeader">
    <%= turbo_frame_tag "paginate_page_#{@sub_orders.current_page}" do %>
      <%@sub_orders.each do |sub| %>
        <%="klass:"+klass%>
      <%end%>
      <% if @sub_orders.next_page %>
        <%= turbo_frame_tag "paginate_page_#{@sub_orders.next_page}", src: filter_supplier_calendars_path(page: @sub_orders.next_page), loading: 'lazy' do %>
          Loading...
        <% end %>
      <%end%>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<%end%>
```

Trying to paginate some orders here, the initial loading of the klass is found however when I paginate is does not keep the value of klass and therefore doesn't display anything.

I've tried adding `locals:{klass: params[:select]}` to where the next_page is being appended but it just adds a data-variable of locals="klass" inside the tag itself

Any ideas on how I can pass this klass variable into the turbo frame?

Comment: it looks as if you need to pass the value of the `select` parameter in the url for the turbo_frame_tag src attribute, maybe as a query string, `filter_supplier_calendars_path(page: @sub_orders.next_page, select: klass)`

Comment: Can you post the code from the related controller? Only seeing the view makes this tough to follow.

Comment: Actually Les already answered it I just dont know how to mark it answered im sorry!

Comment: Either @LesNightingill can post their solution as an answer and Tyler can accept it. Or Tyler can post an answer and accept it as the solution (I think after a waiting period).